# Store mysql query result in two diffrent variable

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT username,userid FROM user WHERE username = 'admin' ";

$result=$conn->store_result();
$result1=$conn->store_result();
```

Can I store same result in two diffrent variable? $result and $result1?

Comment: You can do direct $result1=$result=$conn->store_result();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
$query = "SELECT username,userid FROM user WHERE username = 'admin' ";

$result=$conn->store_result();
$result1=$result;
```

Comment: so when I use $row as $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); and $row = $result1->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) on diffrent part of code?

Comment: why u want to use the same result in different var ?

Comment: better u can use two queries @Pratiksha